# Can't start stand-alone parse.com server on Debian

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, npm, parse-server

There is parse server https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

This is stand alone version of parse.com service.

I have Debian 8.3, fresh installed.
I downloaded parse server from git, perform install, but still can't start service.

I installed this that way:

```
git clone https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server.git
npm install
```

I have this after command

```
npm run start
```

output:

```
You must provide an appId!
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! parse-server@2.1.2 start: `./bin/parse-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server@2.1.2 start script './bin/parse-server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./bin/parse-server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-server
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-server
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/parse/parse-server/bin/npm-debug.log
```

and this after command

```
sudo npm start -- --appId foo --masterKey bar --serverURL http://localhost:1337/parse
```

output:

```
> parse-server@2.1.2 start /root/parse/parse-server
> ./bin/parse-server "--appId" "foo" "--masterKey" "bar" "--serverURL" "http://localhost:1337/parse"


/root/parse/parse-server/lib/requiredParameter.js:8
  throw errorMessage;
  ^
You must provide an appId!

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start" "--" "--appId" "foo" "--masterKey" "bar" "--serverURL" "http://localhost:1337/parse"
npm ERR! node v5.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! parse-server@2.1.2 start: `./bin/parse-server "--appId" "foo" "--masterKey" "bar" "--serverURL" "http://localhost:1337/parse"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server@2.1.2 start script './bin/parse-server "--appId" "foo" "--masterKey" "bar" "--serverURL" "http://localhost:1337/parse"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./bin/parse-server "--appId" "foo" "--masterKey" "bar" "--serverURL" "http://localhost:1337/parse"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-server
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-server
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/parse/parse-server/bin/npm-debug.log
```

In the last command I explicitly specified appId, but the ouput says that appId is not specified.

Where did I go wrong?

**Update 26.02.2016:**

Installation was performed by that command

```
root@parseserver:~/parse/parse-server# npm install --unsafe-perm
```

Output was:

```
> parse-server@2.1.3 prepublish /root/parse/parse-server
> npm run build


> parse-server@2.1.3 build /root/parse/parse-server
> babel src/ -d lib/

src/APNS.js -> lib/APNS.js
src/Adapters/AdapterLoader.js -> lib/Adapters/AdapterLoader.js
src/Adapters/Files/FilesAdapter.js -> lib/Adapters/Files/FilesAdapter.js
src/Adapters/Files/GridStoreAdapter.js -> lib/Adapters/Files/GridStoreAdapter.js
src/Adapters/Files/S3Adapter.js -> lib/Adapters/Files/S3Adapter.js
src/Adapters/Logger/FileLoggerAdapter.js -> lib/Adapters/Logger/FileLoggerAdapter.js
src/Adapters/Logger/LoggerAdapter.js -> lib/Adapters/Logger/LoggerAdapter.js
src/Adapters/Push/OneSignalPushAdapter.js -> lib/Adapters/Push/OneSignalPushAdapter.js
src/Adapters/Push/ParsePushAdapter.js -> lib/Adapters/Push/ParsePushAdapter.js
src/Adapters/Push/PushAdapter.js -> lib/Adapters/Push/PushAdapter.js
src/Adapters/Push/PushAdapterUtils.js -> lib/Adapters/Push/PushAdapterUtils.js
src/Auth.js -> lib/Auth.js
src/Config.js -> lib/Config.js
src/Controllers/AdaptableController.js -> lib/Controllers/AdaptableController.js
src/Controllers/FilesController.js -> lib/Controllers/FilesController.js
src/Controllers/LoggerController.js -> lib/Controllers/LoggerController.js
src/Controllers/PushController.js -> lib/Controllers/PushController.js
src/DatabaseAdapter.js -> lib/DatabaseAdapter.js
src/ExportAdapter.js -> lib/ExportAdapter.js
src/GCM.js -> lib/GCM.js
src/PromiseRouter.js -> lib/PromiseRouter.js
src/RestQuery.js -> lib/RestQuery.js
src/RestWrite.js -> lib/RestWrite.js
src/Routers/AnalyticsRouter.js -> lib/Routers/AnalyticsRouter.js
src/Routers/ClassesRouter.js -> lib/Routers/ClassesRouter.js
src/Routers/FilesRouter.js -> lib/Routers/FilesRouter.js
src/Routers/FunctionsRouter.js -> lib/Routers/FunctionsRouter.js
src/Routers/IAPValidationRouter.js -> lib/Routers/IAPValidationRouter.js
src/Routers/InstallationsRouter.js -> lib/Routers/InstallationsRouter.js
src/Routers/LogsRouter.js -> lib/Routers/LogsRouter.js
src/Routers/PushRouter.js -> lib/Routers/PushRouter.js
src/Routers/RolesRouter.js -> lib/Routers/RolesRouter.js
src/Routers/SchemasRouter.js -> lib/Routers/SchemasRouter.js
src/Routers/SessionsRouter.js -> lib/Routers/SessionsRouter.js
src/Routers/UsersRouter.js -> lib/Routers/UsersRouter.js
src/Schema.js -> lib/Schema.js
src/batch.js -> lib/batch.js
src/cache.js -> lib/cache.js
src/cli/cli-definitions.js -> lib/cli/cli-definitions.js
src/cli/parse-server.js -> lib/cli/parse-server.js
src/cli/utils/commander.js -> lib/cli/utils/commander.js
src/cryptoUtils.js -> lib/cryptoUtils.js
src/global_config.js -> lib/global_config.js
src/httpRequest.js -> lib/httpRequest.js
src/index.js -> lib/index.js
src/middlewares.js -> lib/middlewares.js
src/oauth/OAuth1Client.js -> lib/oauth/OAuth1Client.js
src/oauth/facebook.js -> lib/oauth/facebook.js
src/oauth/github.js -> lib/oauth/github.js
src/oauth/google.js -> lib/oauth/google.js
src/oauth/index.js -> lib/oauth/index.js
src/oauth/instagram.js -> lib/oauth/instagram.js
src/oauth/linkedin.js -> lib/oauth/linkedin.js
src/oauth/meetup.js -> lib/oauth/meetup.js
src/oauth/twitter.js -> lib/oauth/twitter.js
src/password.js -> lib/password.js
src/requiredParameter.js -> lib/requiredParameter.js
src/rest.js -> lib/rest.js
src/testing-routes.js -> lib/testing-routes.js
src/transform.js -> lib/transform.js
src/triggers.js -> lib/triggers.js
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
npm WARN mongodb-core@1.2.32 requires a peer of kerberos@~0.0 but none was installed.
```

Comment: Post updated: added install log.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce this error. Your command line works fine in my system.

Parse is getting pretty many updates now. The newest version is 2.1.3, and has other error messages and other layout than you have. Please try to upgrade and run again.

If you can't do that, please tell which 2.1.2 version you have. Run `git log | head -1` to get exactly the git commit that you are running, to be able to know if this is a Parse error, which only existed a short time.

Comment: Updated to latest version from github (2.1.3) and stil have the same problem.
Anyway, thanks for your research! Got some fresh ideas after your post

Comment: Please update your errors as well. The `You must provide an appId!` does not exist anymore if you upgraded to 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your appId and masterKey in the index.js file.

Check if you already done that

Comment: I don't even find this file. There is no file with this name in project directory:
`root@parseserver:~/parse/parse-server# ls
CHANGELOG.md  LICENSE  README.md  jsconfig.json  node_modules  spec
CONTRIBUTING.md  PATENTS  bin      lib     package.json  src`

Comment: Is my installation complete or I missed something? Install log added to OP.

Comment: From the documentation, you can either have a config.js or supply these on the command line. @Shadow_ this is not the reason for your problems.